# Optional break in aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, nosql-aggregation

I have the following pipeline:

1. Match a single document from collection `collection1`.
2. Take key `k_id`, which is `ObjectId` and lookup for another single document in `collection2` with that `_id`.
3. `$unwind` the result.

The problem is, I am not sure `k_id` exists and `collection2` contains the document I lookup for. In that case I'd like to do some checks and break aggregation pipeline after the first step. I didn't found any operator with similar functionality.

For now I do some complicated mess.

```js
db['collection1'].aggregate([

  {$match: ...},

  // make field that always exist and put either $k_id or null there
  {$addFields: {
     k_id_ensured: {$ifNull: ['$k_id', null]}
  }},

  // $document_unensured may be empty array in case no documents found
  {$lookup: {
    from: 'collection2',
    ...,
    as: 'document_unensured'
  }},

  // replace empty array with [null], ...
  {$addFields: {
    document_ensured: {
       $cond: {
          // (if $document_unensured is empty array...)
          if: {$eq: [ {$size, '$document_unensured'}, 0 ]},
          // (...then make it contain at least `null`)
          then: [ null ],
          else: '$document_unensured'
       }
    }
  }},

  // ...because after unwinding empty array the whole
  // document will just dissappear
  {$unwind: {path: '$document_ensured'}},

  {$project: /*delete all non needed fields*/}

])
```

Is there more elegant way to do it?

Comment: $unwind has an option to preserve input documents when the field being unwound is empty or missing.

Comment: oh, that makes it all a little bit easier, thanks.